# how to uplode wordpress site on server using ftp

Tags: 16.04, wordpress

I have installed wordpress locally on ubuntu 16.04, I have fully created a site and now want to push it on a server, I have installed filezilla to upload files of my wordpress site, I wanted to know how to get the files of the site I created, where can I find them.

Answer (score 0):

The files will be where you installed them to.
Just remember that you will need to create a backup of the database as well and restore it on the remote machine.
And remeber to configure the web server config file for the site matching to the local version.